# How to embed Ibus preedit text into Emacs?

Tags: input-method

I'd like to ask is it possible to totally embed Ibus preedit text into the Emacs windows?

In my Ibus Preferences, I did tick the option "Embed preedit text in application window", however, the preedit text still appears in a separate popup dialog like this.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thank you very much!